# SQL login only works after visiting login page

Tags: php, mysql

I am stumped. I have a login.php page that contains the SQL login info (hostname, database, username, password) included at the top of my index.php page (using require_once). The login info is within a conditional statement that determines whether I am on the remote server or the local testing server and offers up the correct login info. Now this is where it gets weird, it doesn't work (as in it does not make a connection with the database) when I go directly to the index.php page on the remote server however it does work on the testing server and it works if I visit the login.php site on the remote server first (which doesn't echo anything) and then visit the index.php page on the remote server. I have caches disabled. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? try it yourself by visiting http://distantfuturejosh.com/playground/pendingaxioms first (it won't work), then visiting http://distantfuturejosh.com/playground/pendingaxioms/login.php (a blank page is served) and then returning to http://distantfuturejosh.com/playground/pendingaxioms (it will work and you'll see the images appear).

here is the login.php page:

```
<?php

    $requesturi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pos = strpos($requesturi, "www.distantfuturejosh.com");

    if ($pos === 0)
    {
        $db_hostname = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_database = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_username = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_password = "xxxxxxxx";
    }
    else
    {
        $db_hostname = "localhost";
        $db_database = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_username = "root";
        $db_password = "root";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Homepage works fine for me when I visit it first, but that could be persistent state. Try echoing out the value of `$requesturi` and `$pos` and see if they are what you expect.

Comment: note that everytime a php script is run a new database connection must be made.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
session_start();
```

at beginning of your file.

Comment: I added `session_start();` at the beginning of the login file (after `<?php` of course) but it behaved exactly as before. I also tried adding it to the index page (before the `require_once 'login.php';`) but observed no change.

Comment: Just print the value of of $pos after this $pos = strpos($requesturi, "www.distantfuturejosh.com");

Comment: you know what, I tried that before, well I used echo instead and it does fix it. Why do I have to echo the variable before it can be used in the conditional statement? And now I have an ugly "0" at the top of my page.

Comment: I think the problem is $pos is coming as a string and your are using === operator may be convert it == operator first. Then check again. If that does not work then try converting $pos to an integer like this intVal($pos) and then try comparing it like if(intVal($pos)===0)?

Comment: Well, I thought that was the solution chandresh_cool but now that I've added the intVal() function the remote site works and now the local site doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

try using `if ($pos === false)` instead of `if ($pos === 0)` like this

```
<?php

    $requesturi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $pos = strpos($requesturi, "distantfuturejosh");

    if ($pos === false)
    {  //local
        $db_hostname = "localhost";
        $db_database = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_username = "root";
        $db_password = "root";
    }
    else
    {  //remote
        $db_hostname = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_database = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_username = "xxxxxxxx";
        $db_password = "xxxxxxxx";
    }

?>
```

I suppose you check user login and include `login.php` in your other PHP pages with `include /subfolder/login.php;`

Comment: do you mean, when you run at your local , it does not go to the `else` statement? or it goes there, but can not connect to your localhost database?

Comment: When I visit http://localhost/pendingaxioms the page loads but the images do not. I assume because it didn't connect to the database because the credentials are wrong. I mean if I delete the if statement and just use credentials for the local server it works fine locally, but I'm trying to avoid having to change the credentials back and forth. And guys, isn't it weird that if I visit the login.php page first it works? I still want to know why that is...